# Filtering pandas dataframe by introspecting each element of a row

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, series

I have a dataframe that contains an object in a column.

for example:

```
df['id_original'].iloc[0].Class
Out[20]: u'Classtype1'

df['id_original'].iloc[1].Class
Out[20]: u'Classtype2'
```

How can I filter the dataframe that I only get the rows where the row 'id_original' contains a objects with the property Class of Classtype1. Or even better. in combination with `.isin(allowed_class_type_list)`?

Is there any way to achieve this with .isin or will I have to iterate over all the rows with iterrows? An elegant one-line solution is preferred.

Comment: are they strings? Is this what you want `df[df['id_original'].isin(['Classtype1'])]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.loc[df['id_original'].apply(lambda x: x.Class in allowed_class_type_list)]
```

Consider below minified example:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, class_):
        self.Class = class_

ex1 = Example('class1')
ex2 = Example('class2')
ex3 = Example('class3')
ex4 = Example('class4')

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id_original':[ex1, ex2, ex2, ex1, ex4, ex3, ex3, ex4]
})

allowed_class_type_list = ['class1', 'class4']
```

You can filter using:

```
df.loc[df['id_original'].apply(lambda x: x.Class in allowed_class_type_list)]
```

Output:

```
                   id_original
0   <__main__.Example object at 0x000000000A597390>
3   <__main__.Example object at 0x000000000A597390>
4   <__main__.Example object at 0x000000000A597B00>
7   <__main__.Example object at 0x000000000A597B00>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `apply` to get a series of True/False and use it as mask on the dataframe

```
mask = df['id_original'].apply(lambda x: x.Class in allowed_class_list)
df.loc[mask]
```

The same logic bit cleaner

```
mask = df['id_original'].apply(lambda x: x.Class).isin(allowed_class_list)
df.loc[mask]
```